# What does "This tweet was manufactured in a facility that also processes triggers." mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

The following tweet is from [Paul Graham](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Graham_%28computer_programmer%29) https://twitter.com/paulg/status/664170540559564800. Is he speaking about the brains ability to process interruptions while tweeting?

Comment: He's speaking about the health warning you might see on a package of snacks -- "These xxx were manufactured in a facility that also processes peanuts."

Comment: Following up Hot Licks' comment, they are using the word trigger to mean "something that causes anger, rage, disgust, or offense." In other words, reading the tweet might offend you because of association. Or something along those lines...

Answer (score 3):

As HotLicks notes, the phrasing is that of the warning on some food packaging:  "XXX product was manufactured in a facility that also processes YYY."  If you're allergic to peanuts but not almonds, and XXX="almond butter" an YYY="peanuts," then you might want to avoid this brand of almond butter that might be slightly contaminated with peanuts.

*Triggers* is shorthand for "[trigger warnings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trauma_trigger#Trigger_warnings)," a label used by the politically correct to warn people that some material might offend them.  From what I can tell, Paul Graham is opposed to the use of trigger warnings, so his tweet means that people who are in favor of them might be upset at his opposition.